# scrapy internal links + pipeline and mongodb collection relationships

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy, relationship

I am watching videos and reading some articles about how scrapy works with python and inserting to mongodb.

Then two questions popped up which either I am not googling with the correct keywords or just couldn't find the answer.

Anyways, let me take example on this tutorial site `https://blog.scrapinghub.com` to **scrape** blog posts.

I know we can get things like the title, author, date.  But what if I want to get the content too?  Which I need to click on more in order to go into another url then get the content.  How can this be done though?

Then I either want the content to be the same dict as title, author, date or maybe title, author, date can be in one collection and having the content in another collection but the same post should be related though.

I am kinda lost when I thought of this, can someone give me suggestions / advices for this kind of idea?

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the situation you described, you will scrape the content from the main page, `yield` a new Request to the read more page and send the data you already scraped together with the `Request`. When the new request callbacks it's parsing method, all the data scraped in the previous page will be available.

**The recommended way** to send the data with the request is to use [cb_kwargs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.cb_kwargs). Quite often you may find people/tutorials using the [meta](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta) param, as `cb_kwargs` only became available on Scrapy v1.7+.

Here is a example to illustrate:

```
class MySpider(Spider):

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.xpath('//div[@id="title"]/text()').get()
        author = response.xpath('//div[@id="author"]/text()').get()
        scraped_data = {'title': title, 'author': author}

        read_more_url = response.xpath('//div[@id="read-more"]/@href').get()
        yield Request(
            url=read_more_url,
            callback=self.parse_read_more,
            cb_kwargs={'main_page_data': scraped_data}
        )

    def parse_read_more(self, response, main_page_data):
        # The data from the main page will be received as a param in this method.
        content = response.xpath('//article[@id="content"]/text()').get()
        yield {
            'title': main_page_data['title'],
            'author': main_page_data['author'],
            'content': content
        }
```

*Notice that the key in the cb_kwargs must be the same as the param name in the callback function.*

Comment: nice :D thanks for this, works perfectly also I believe the callback `parse_read_more` should be `self.parse_read_more` ^_^ by the way, does that mean if I have lots more layer to scrap from, I need to keep yield Request then passing callback?

Comment: Nice catch, just fixed. Every Request will need a callback function to handle the response. And if the information scraped in Page 1 needs to be in the item yielded at the "request layer" 10, you will need to keep  passing it on `cb_kwargs`. Obviously, if the information is independent, you can `yield` it at any time.

Comment: so if let's say info scraped in page 1 does not need to be used in `request layer` 10, I do not need to use the `cb_kwargs`? let's take your example above, if my title and author in page 1 is not needed in `parse_read_more` I actually do not even need to pass `cb_kwargs` and I can just `yield {'content': content} and as a result, my item will still have title, author, content.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. If the information is to be contained in the same Item, like you want your Item to have title, author and content, but title and author are in different page then content, you'll need to have them passed into the functions as `cb_kwags` until you finally yield the Item. I just meant that you don't need to pass into `cb_kwargs` independent info, as in no link with the new page, and could be yielded independently. **As a rule of thumb**, if the scraped data isn't yielded or passed into another function, it's lost.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation :D I was playing around with it after asking you :P

Comment: by the way, sorry to bother, wondering if you know much about scrapy passing argument into pipeline? I got stuck with another question wonder if you able to give me a hand?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63387991/typeerror-init-missing-1-required-positional-argument-with-scrapy-passing