# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument with scrapy passing params to pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy, arguments, pipeline

Normally I know what this error means but somehow I believe I did pass in the argument though

I am playing around scrapy and inside pipeline, I figured if I am scraping through few different sites or pages, I want them to let's say all output json file but with different json of course so I can know which json belongs to which website

So I created a service folder and inside there's a file called pipeline

so inside this `pipeline.py`

I created a class such below

```
import json
import os

class JsonWriterPipeline(object):
    """
    write all items to a file, most likely json file
    """
    def __init__(self, filename):
        print(filename)  # this does prints the filename though
        self.file = open(filename, 'w')

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file.write('[')

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        # remove the last two char which is ',\n' then add closing bracket ']'
        self.file.seek(self.file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END) - 2)
        self.file.write(']')

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + ",\n"
        self.file.write(line)
        return item
```

then inside the original `pipeline.py` under root folder I have something like this

```
from scrape.services.pipeline import JsonWriterPipeline



JsonWriterPipeline('testing.json')  # so I have passed the filename argument as `'testing.json'`
```

but I just keep on getting the error, also as mentioned above, when I do `print(filename)` it prints out properly though.

if I am not passing in the filename and instead of having a static filename, it works perfectly but of course I want it dynamic that's why I created a class so I can reuse it

Anyone has ideas

EDIT:
as `Gallaecio` below mentioned then realized so pipelines does not take parameters, I did some googling for those answers saying pipeline accepts parameters in such ways are if the parameters are passed through command line not inside the code itself

Thanks for any suggestions and advices given.

Comment: Pipelines do not accept parameters. Assuming you also configured Scrapy to use this pipeline class, then when Scrapy creates an instance it does not pass a `filename` parameter to it, hence the issue. If I got that right, then what you need to ask is how to pass parameters to pipelines.

Comment: @Gallaecio great, I guess that's the reason why it's not working then....let me edit my question

Comment: First search the internet, there may be an answer already for the new question.

Comment: @Gallaecio for sure :D thanks for such advice ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of an alternative which is instead of creating new object and passing the argument while creating.  Maybe try something like inheritance

sample below

inside `service/pipeline.py`

```
import json
import os


class JsonWriterPipeline(object):
    """
    write all items to a file, most likely json file
    """
    filename = 'demo.json'  # instead of passing argument create variable for the class

    def __init__(self):
        self.file = open(self.filename, 'w+')

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file.write('[')

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        # remove the last two char which is ',\n' then add closing bracket ']'
        self.file.seek(self.file.seek(0, os.SEEK_END) - 2)
        self.file.write(']')
        return

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + ",\n"
        self.file.write(line)
        return item
```

inside the original `pipeline.py`

```
from scrape.services.pipeline import JsonWriterPipeline

class JsonWriterPipelineA(JsonWriterPipeline):
    filename = 'a.json'

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


class JsonWriterPipelineB(JsonWriterPipeline):
    filename = 'b.json'

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

this is the alternative way I can think of, hope this helps you